# Citizen Patrol Badge Requirements

Tags: support

I am little confused on the requirements for the Citizen Patrol badge. I interpreted the requirement as the first post that I flagged. However, I have flagged at least one post and I still have not received the badge. Have I interpreted the requirement wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The requirement is that you flag a post as [spam or offensive](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6120/citizen-patrol-badge-not-awarded): flagging something for moderator attention doesn't count. It also takes a little bit of time for the system to recognize it: from my experience, it takes an hour or two.

Comment: Ok...now I understand. Thank you